# Undo Google Chrome inspector's magnifying glass tool?

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector

[image]

1. Open the inspector on any element.
2. Select the Computed tab.
3. Hover to the left of any style you will see the magnifying glass.
4. Click the magnifying glass and it will filter the Styles tab to only relevant results.

Now, how do I deselect this feature? The only way I have found is to close the inspector completely and reopen it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clicking the magnifying glass is apparently a shortcut for using the "Find in Styles" feature of the Styles panel. Thus, after clicking it, the item you clicked will appear in the "Find in Styles" field at the bottom of the Styles panel, highlighted in yellow. When you hover over the field, a Ⓧ icon appears at the far right side of the field. Clicking the icon clears the field, and the Styles panel is back to normal.

Here's how it look**ed** in action (see edit below for current location of search filter):

[image]

You won't be returned to the "Computed" panel, though.

**Edit 2015-09-08:**

With some recent update to Chrome, the search field has moved. Now it appears at the top of the CSS column, in the same row as the "New Style Rule" (plus), "Toggle Element State" (pushpin), and "Animations Controls" (stacked diamonds) buttons:

[image]

To clear your search, just delete the filter text (e.g., "vertical" as pictured).

Comment: Ok that's not very noticeable down there at the bottom. Everything you said works perfectly. Now I can start using this feature. Thanks.

Comment: I only discovered it this week. I tried to show it to a coworker while we were pairing on some styling issues, but his copy of Chrome doesn't have it. I don't know what I did to get it, but I'm glad.

And yeah: As an interaction designer, I'll take a lesson from this. What seems perfectly obvious to the designer may be entirely invisible to a user.